# How to set menu with Fragments tabs in Tab-Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I use TabLayout and ViewPager in Android App.I want set the Menu Button in Right side of TabLayout.

---

> Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blue"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/Black"
        app:tabMode="fixed">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Low">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question since it is really hard to understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: You can read this article https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a

Comment: I update my problem please check it again and tell the Right solution.